# SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) suddenly stopped working?

Tags: excel, vba

I dont know why SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) suddenly stopped working for me today, I had been working with it all day and it was doing exactly what I was expecting, however all of sudden it stopped working, and now a simple code that returns the value of a cell in a filtered table, returns the value of a filtered cell. And when I want to select the filtered table, now it selects the whole table (including the filtered rows).

```
Set bookprincipal = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Tabla = bookprincipal.ListObjects("MainTable")
Set rangotablafiltrada = Tabla.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

   Debug.Print rangotablafiltrada(3, 75)
   rangotablafiltrada.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

Comment: How do you see that **the whole table is selected**? It shouldn't do that. Please, try adding the next testing code, after your last code line? `Debug.Print Selection.Address, Tabla.DataBodyRange.Address`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`? The same address? I cannot believe that...

Comment: Did you try replace `ActiveWorkbook` by `ThisWorkbook` if the macro is in the same workbook than your datas ? Maybe you have multiple workbooks open and VBA take the data from the wrong wb.

Comment: Which Excel version do you use? before XL2010 you couldn't use specialcells when there were more than 8192 areas

Comment: Why are you calling `SpecialCells` twice?

Comment: Thanks guys I have found the problem. It looks like before filtering a table on a column, one has to sort that column first or the rows later will look like: 12, 48, 120, 240..., however when it's first sorted, and then filtered, the rows are numerated consecutively: 1, 2, 3, 4...
It seems that if the range is "splitted", xlCellTypeVisible doesnt work well, it has to be a consecutive range to work.

Comment: You cannot index into a multi-area range using ` (row, column)`